# Associating AWS ec2 instance with elastic ip using ansible playbook

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I've created a code and it is successful in associating my instance with the EIP. However, my public_ip addr remains unchanged, i.e the address given to the vm before association with elastic ip. Here's the code,

```html
---
  - name: Provision an EC2 Instance
    hosts: local
    connection: local
    gather_facts: False
    tags: provisioning
    vars:
      instance_type: t2.micro
      security_group: My secure group
      image: ami-5b673c34
      keypair: mynodes
      region: ap-south-1
      count: 1

    tasks:

      - name: Launch the new EC2 Instance
        local_action: ec2
                      group={{ security_group }}
                      instance_type={{ instance_type}}
                      image={{ image }}
                      wait=true
                      region={{ region }}
                      keypair={{ keypair }}
                      count={{count}}
        register: ec2

      - name: Get the Ip address
        debug: var=ec2.instances[0].public_dns_name

      - name: Allocating elastic IP to instance
        ec2_eip:
          in_vpc: yes
          reuse_existing_ip_allowed: yes
          state: present
          region: "{{ region }}"
          device_id: "{{ item }}"
        with_items: "{{ ec2.instance_ids }}"
          #device_id: "{{ ec2.instances[0] }}"
        #register: instance_eip

      - debug: msg=ec2.instances[0].public_ip


      - #name: eip with instance
        #pause:
          #seconds: 30

      - name: Add the newly created EC2 instance(s) to the local host group 
        local_action: lineinfile
                      dest="/etc/ansible/hosts"
                      regexp={{ item.private_ip }}
                      insertafter="[node3]" line={{ item.private_ip }}
        with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"


      - name: Wait for SSH to come up
        local_action: wait_for
                      host={{ item.public_ip }}
                      port=22
                      state=started
        with_items: '{{ ec2.instances }}'

      - name: Add tag to Instance(s)
        local_action: ec2_tag resource={{ item.id }} region={{ region }} state=present
        with_items: '{{ ec2.instances }}'
        args:
          tags:
            Name: node3
```

So my code is currently running perfectly if I do not assign it an elastic ip. But when I do, i'm somehow unable to execute the task of ssh'ing into my newly created vm.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on Stack Overflow please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: "i'm somehow unable to execute the task of ssh'ing into my newly created vm"
Can you post a error message? Maybe we can help you, but we need more details

Comment: Well, when i'm adding the host ip to my hosts list, it takes the previously assigned IP of the VM, i.e before the allocation of the elastic IP. Thus an unused ip is now added to my hosts list. I think that maybe because i'm using " with_items: '{{ ec2.instances }}' " and ec2 is a register variable which doesn't have the elastic ip stored. How do I modify my code? @flxPeters